# Is there a way to prevent a file from being completely loaded by a software?

Tags: file, limit

Is there a way to limit a hard drive from reading a certain file? Ex. It's given to Program A the order to open a .txt file. Program B overloads the .txt file opening hundreds times a second. Program A is unable to open the txt file.

So I'm trying to stress test a game engine that relies on extracting all used textures from a single file at once. I think that this extraction method is causing some core problems to the game developing experience of the engine overall. My theory is that the problem is caused by the slow reading time of some hard drives. But I'm not sure if I'm right on this, and I needed I way to test this out.

Answer (score 1):

Most operating systems support file locking and file sharing so that you can establish rules for processes that share access to a file.

.NET, for example (which runs on Windows, Linux, and MacOS), provides the facility to open a file in a variety of [sharing modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=net-5.0).

For very rapid access like you describe, you may want to consider a [memory-mapped file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files). They are supported on many operating systems and via various programming languages. .NET also [provides support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?view=net-5.0).